# delete one by one the vertices of a curve?

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I have a spiral shaped nurbsPath, and i need to delete each vertex from first to last, one for each frame of animation. Can anyone come up with a phyton script to acomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't actually want a python script to delete points on your curve. If you delete the points on the curve they will be gone, you will need to create new points or reload the blend file if you want to run your animation a second time.

I think animating the curve's bevel factor is closer to what you want.

[image: sample bevel animation]

Comment: On frame 1, right click the "start", and "insert keyframe". On frame 100, add another keyframe. :D Animated.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, is not "exactly" what I needed, but very useful :)